# Galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(f/\mathbb{Q})$ of the polynomial $f(x)=(x^2+3)(x^2-2)$

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory

> Find the Galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(f/\mathbb{Q})$ of the polynomial $f(x)=(x^2+3)(x^2-2)$.

Any explanations during the demonstration, will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you do $g(x)=x^2+3$? Can you do $h(x)=x^2-2$? Can you see how to fit them together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The splitting field of $f$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, i\sqrt{3})$ and since
$$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, i\sqrt{3}):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, i\sqrt{3}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}]=2\cdot 2=4$$
the Galois group has four element.
Since every $\sigma\in$ Gal$(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, i\sqrt{3})/\mathbb{Q})$ must take $\sqrt{2}$ and $i\sqrt{3}$ to another root of Irr$(\sqrt{2}, \mathbb{Q})=x^2-2$ and Irr($i\sqrt{3}, \mathbb{Q})=x^2+3$ respectively, we see that $\sigma(\sqrt{2})=\pm \sqrt{2}$ and $\sigma(i\sqrt{3})=\pm i\sqrt{3}$. Thus every element in Gal$(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, i\sqrt{3})/\mathbb{Q})$ has order $1$ or $2$. As the only groups of order $4$ are $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $V_4$ and our group is not cyclic, it must be that the Galois group of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $V_4$.

Comment: $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[]{3},\sqrt[]{2})$ is not the splitting field since $x^2 + 3$ has complex roots.

Comment: @Islands Well, that was embarrassing. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Hints for you to understand and/or prove:

(1) If $\,\sigma\in\,\text{Gal}\,(f/\Bbb Q)\,$ ,  it **must** be that

$$\sigma(\sqrt 2)=\pm\sqrt 2\;,\;\;\sigma(i\sqrt 3)=\pm i\sqrt 3$$

(2) We have that $\,x^2+3\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)[x]\,$ is irreducible (**there** , not only in $\,\Bbb Q[x]\,$ !)

(3)  We have that $\;\{1\,,\,\sqrt 2\,,\,i\sqrt 3\,,\,i\sqrt 6\}\;$ is a basis for $\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2,i\sqrt 3)/\Bbb Q\;$

Comment: Same mistake as other poster. $x^2 + 3$ has complex roots.

Comment: What do you know? Oh, well...hehe. Anyway, most of the basic principles shown there apply in the actual case. I shall edit now, and thanks.

Comment: This is my easiest-to-edit answer so far: I just changed/added some 6 characters!

Answer (score 0):

By tower law we know that $[\mathbb Q(i\sqrt[]{3}, \sqrt[]{2}):\mathbb Q]= 4$, since $[\mathbb Q(i\sqrt[]{3}, \sqrt[]{2}):\mathbb Q(\sqrt[]{2})]=2$ and $[\mathbb Q(\sqrt[]{2}):\mathbb Q]=2$.

Let $i$ be the inclusion map $i:\mathbb Q \hookrightarrow \mathbb Q(i\sqrt[]{3}, \sqrt[]{2})$. Then $i(x^2 - 2) =x^2 - 2$ and $x^2-2$ has roots $\sqrt[]{2}$, $-\sqrt[]{2}$ in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[]{2})$, so there is a monomorphism $j$ extending $i$ such that $j: \mathbb Q(\sqrt[]{2}) \hookrightarrow \mathbb  Q(i\sqrt[]{3}, \sqrt[]{2})$ given by $j: \sqrt[]{2} \mapsto \pm\sqrt[]{2}$.

Then $j(x^2 + 3)=x^2+3$ and $x^2 + 3$ has roots $\pm i \sqrt[]{3}$ in $\mathbb Q(i\sqrt[]{3}, \sqrt[]{2})$. Hence there is a monomorphism $\sigma$ extending $j$ such that $\sigma: \mathbb Q(i\sqrt[]{3}, \sqrt[]{2}) \hookrightarrow \mathbb Q(i\sqrt[]{3}, \sqrt[]{2})$ given by $\sigma:i\sqrt[]{3} \mapsto \pm i \sqrt[]{3}$ and $\sigma: \sqrt[]{2} \mapsto \pm\sqrt[]{2}$

But $\sigma$ is actually an automorphism since it is a $\mathbb Q$-linear map on vector spaces of the same degree. Therefore $\sigma \in Gal(f)$ and $|Gal(f)| = 4$